# Another flipping the coin problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics

The following is a question from "The Probability Tutoring Book" by Carol Ash.

> A coin has $P(Head) = p$ and $P(Tail) = 1-p = q$. Find the prob that it takes 10 tosses to get a head and a tail(i.e. at least one of each)

My Attempt:
$$P(\geq 1 H\ and \geq 1T) = 1 - P(0\ H\ \cup 0\ T)$$
(By applying the complement rule)

$$P(0\ H\ \cup\ 0\ T) = P(0\ H) + P(0\ T) - P(0\ H\ \cap\ 0\ T) $$
(By Inclusion - Exclusion Principle)

$$P(0\ H\ \cap\ 0\ T) = 0$$
(Since we have to at least get a head or a tail from every toss)
$$P(0\ H\ \cup\ 0\ T) = q^{10} + p^{10} - 0$$

Putting this all together,
$$P(\geq 1 H\ and \geq 1T) = 1 - P(0\ H\ \cup 0\ T) \\ = 1 - q^{10} - p^{10}$$

However according to the solutions at the back of the book:
$$P(\geq 1 H\ and \geq 1T) = P(H^9T\ \cup\ T^9H) = p^9q + q^9p$$
Isn't this just the probability that we get a ***specific ordering*** of HHHHHHHHT or TTTTTTTTTH.

Who is right?

Comment: Yes, if if takes $10$ tosses to get one of each, then either the first $9$ tosses were heads and the tenth tails, or vice versa.

Comment: The book is.  You need those specific orderings, because either the tails has to come tenth, after a sequence of nine heads, or the heads has to come tenth, after a sequence of nine tails.  What you've calculated is the probability that after ten heads, we have at least one heads and one tails—you've calculated it by eliminating only those cases where we get ten heads or ten tails.

Comment: "*The probability that it takes 10 tosses to get a head and a tail*" (*i.e. that the after nine tosses we have not seen both and it is only after the tenth toss that both are seen*) is different than "*The probability that within 10 tosses we have seen both*" (*i.e. that having seen both could have happened sooner than the tenth*).  Reworded, letting $X$ be the random variable indicating the first point in time where we have seen both, you calculated $Pr(X\leq 10)$ but you were tasked with calculating $Pr(X=10)$

Comment: As an aside, I would not have written the event that we are actually tasked with calculating as $\geq 1H~and~\geq 1T$ since as alluded to already the event is more restrictive than that, so I question whether the solution in the back of the book had it written like that.

Answer (score 1):

The words "it **takes** $10$ tosses to get a head and a tail" means the in the first $9$ tosses, you repeatedly only get one of them, and only after the 10th toss, you receive both.

Your $P(\geq 1 H\ and \geq 1T)$ does not respect the fact that all first $9$ tosses yield the same result.

The probabilty that is asked for is $P(\{\text{first head in 10th toss}\} \cup \{\text{first tail in 10th toss}\})$.

So, yes, the question is for a specific odering, settled by the words "it takes", which means "only then and not before". In any other ordering, it would have taken less than $10$ tosses to get at least one head and one tail.